# SharePoint Test Site

Tags: document-library, permissions, site-template, site-creation

I want to practice on how to use Sharepoint, for example: setup a site, manage library and give permissions. Is there a demo site I can use to practice this?

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a SharePoint site in your tenant for testing purposes or you could apply for the Microsoft 365 developer program which would give you a developer tenant where you can test:

[Microsoft 365 developer program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program)